# Android studio - import project issue

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL8DL.png)
I am currently using Bumblee version of android studio. When i am trying to import project it is showing " This specifed  file already exists"
Your help will be appreciated

This image shows error that I am facing

Comment: Take a screenshot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.